# Two column centered (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following Razor View

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row well">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <h2>Create</h2>
        <h4>Create Advert</h4>
    </div>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="text-danger">@ViewBag.Message</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-5">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 " })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("CountryDropDown", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Country" })
                        @Html.Hidden("Countries", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "HiddenCountry" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("CountryDropDown", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subregion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subregion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subregion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.CheckBox("PriceCheck", isChecked: false) @Html.DisplayName("Price negotiable")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BuildingFloorsId, "Floors", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("FloorsDropDown", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BuildingFloorsId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Area, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Area, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Area, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("TPP", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Area, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Area, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Type of construction", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Interior, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Interior, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Exterior, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Exterior, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Exterior, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdvertisementCategoryId, "Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("AdvertisementCategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlProductCategory" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdvertisementCategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("StateDropDown", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "State" })
                        @Html.Hidden("States", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "HiddenState" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("StateDropDown", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Currency", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Currency", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Currency" })
                        @Html.Hidden("Currencies", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "HiddenCurrency" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("Currency", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FloorId, "Floor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("FloorDropDown", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FloorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TelephonNum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TelephonNum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "TelNum" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TelephonNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomsNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomsNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomsNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Interior, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Interior, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Interior, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetCaptchaImage","Captcha")" style="width:300px;" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Enter Code", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBox("CaptchaText", "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" style="width:300px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

I use the latest version of Bootstrap. When I run that code, the result is not good. [image]
The columns and the row is not centered. The input fields with their labels are block elements and the class name: "text-center" doesn't work; I tried with "block-center" but nothing. I also tried with offsetting. If you have some ideas, will be great.

Comment: Can you show us your output HTML, that's going to be a better representation of what we can correct for.  Immediately I'm seeing some Bootstrap framework issues like combining `.row` with `.well`, you don't have the form itself inside a `.row` or a `.col-*-*` which is probably why it isn't centering properly... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are combining certain Bootstrap styles conflict with how the framework is designed to be used.  Grid elements should never have design components affixed to them (ie. `class="row well"` as design elements add additional margin and padding that can disrupt the Grid flow.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
          
          <div class="well text-center">
        <h2>Create</h2>
            <h4>Create Advert</h4>
            </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="row">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
      
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <select name="" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <select name="" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <select name="" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <select name="" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <select name="" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <select name="" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

          
    </form>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Correcting those inconsistencies results in your form structure aligning correctly, although it should be noted that Bootstrap's `<label>` does have issues with longer labels (the label will simply extend down in a rather unappealing manner).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! But how to center all of col-xs-6?

Comment: If you mean you do not want the `.container` to take up 100% of the screen, use `.container-fluid` instead to force a fixed width.  That will center them on your screen.

Comment: I want to center all the inputs and labels, because now they are in left side.

Comment: In order to accomplish that you would have to bypass the framework Bootstrap has setup for its forms.  You can do that by removing classes like `.control-label` and using `.text-center` but I must say, this strikes me as potentially disrupting the user experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's this part that is causing your problem **class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"**

something like this should work alright:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row well">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2>Create</h2>
      <h4>Create Advert</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye68ghnv/)